# Laravel 5.8 - The credentials do not match our records / attemptLogin function return always false

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-authentication

I'm trying to implements authentication system with Laravel 5.8 version.
I have run `php artisan make:auth` and made some litlle changes in the code to adapt with what i need.

I have created users with my Eloquent Model, with hashed password created with the `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash` class.

But right now i can't authenticate myself on my own application and i don't understand why i have everytime the error `These credentials do not match our records`.

So here is my model `App\User` :

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use LdapRecord\Laravel\Auth\HasLdapUser;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use LdapRecord\Laravel\Auth\AuthenticatesWithLdap;
use LdapRecord\Laravel\Auth\LdapAuthenticatable;

/**
 * Class User
 * 
 * @property int $ID_USER
 * @property string $LASTNAME
 * @property string $FIRSTNAME
 * @property string $ACTIVE_DIRECTORY_USER
 * @property int $ID_ROLE
 * @property string $password
 * @property Role $role
 *
 * @package App\Models
 */
class User extends Authenticatable 
{

    use Notifiable;
    
    /**
     * The object classes of the LDAP model.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    public static $objectClasses = [];
    protected $table = 'users';
    protected $primaryKey = 'ID_USER';
    public $incrementing = false;
    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $casts = [
        'ID_USER' => 'int',
        'ID_ROLE' => 'int'
    ];

    protected $fillable = [
        'ID_USER',
        'LASTNAME',
        'FIRSTNAME',
        'ACTIVE_DIRECTORY_USER',
        'ID_ROLE',
        'password'
    ];

    public function role()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Role::class, 'ID_ROLE');
    }
}
```

Auth configuration :

```php
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Defaults
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default authentication "guard" and password
    | reset options for your application. You may change these defaults
    | as required, but they're a perfect start for most applications.
    |
    */

    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Guards
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Next, you may define every authentication guard for your application.
    | Of course, a great default configuration has been defined for you
    | here which uses session storage and the Eloquent user provider.
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | Supported: "session", "token"
    |
    */

    'guards' => [
        // 'web' => [
        //     'driver' => 'session',
        //     'provider' => 'ldap',
        // ],
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users'
        ],
        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | User Providers
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | If you have multiple user tables or models you may configure multiple
    | sources which represent each model / table. These sources may then
    | be assigned to any extra authentication guards you have defined.
    |
    | Supported: "database", "eloquent"
    |
    */

    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Resetting Passwords
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may specify multiple password reset configurations if you have more
    | than one user table or model in the application and you want to have
    | separate password reset settings based on the specific user types.
    |
    | The expire time is the number of minutes that the reset token should be
    | considered valid. This security feature keeps tokens short-lived so
    | they have less time to be guessed. You may change this as needed.
    |
    */

    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
    ],

];
```

The LoginController :

```php
<?php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use LdapRecord\Container;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */
    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    /**
     * Get the login username to be used by the controller.
     */
    public function username() {
        return 'ACTIVE_DIRECTORY_USER';
    }
}
```

The form from the view :

```php
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">
                        @csrf

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="ACTIVE_DIRECTORY_USER" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __("Nom d'utilisateur") }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="ACTIVE_DIRECTORY_USER" type="text" class="form-control @error('ACTIVE_DIRECTORY_USER') is-invalid @enderror" name="ACTIVE_DIRECTORY_USER" value="{{ old('ACTIVE_DIRECTORY_USER') }}" required autocomplete="ACTIVE_DIRECTORY_USER" autofocus>

                                @error('ACTIVE_DIRECTORY_USER')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Mot de passe') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" name="password" required autocomplete="current-password">

                                @error('password')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                <div class="form-check">
                                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember" {{ old('remember') ? 'checked' : '' }}>

                                    <label class="form-check-label" for="remember">
                                        {{ __('Se souvenir de moi') }}
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                            <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    {{ __('Connexion') }}
                                </button>

                                @if (Route::has('password.request'))
                                    <a class="btn btn-link" href="{{ route('password.request') }}">
                                        {{ __('Mot de passe oublié ?') }}
                                    </a>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

I have snoop a little in the `AuthenticatesUsers` trait and it seems that issue come from the `attemptLogin` function because it return false everytimes...
Don't understand how i can fix this...

Comment: can you update the LoginController code here, it looks like a paste from auth config.  Also can do you have a users table with users and passwords seeded?

Comment: @Cameron yep sorry it's edited. Yes i have a users table call "users" with hashed passwords

Comment: I think the return ACTIVE_DIRECTORY_USER may be an issue.  lemme check some of my sites

Comment: ACTIVE_DIRECTORY_USER is the field that i want to use as username.

Comment: question, are you passing ACTIVE_DIRECTORY_USER as the form input in favor of username on the login page?

Comment: I don't understand why it can be that, i have followed the documentation to customize the username : https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authentication

Comment: check resources/views/auth/login.blade.php |                                  
<input id="email" type="email" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="ACTIVE_DIRECTORY_USER" value="{{ old('ACTIVE_DIRECTORY_USER') }}" required autocomplete="ACTIVE_DIRECTORY_USER" autofocus>   or if you are using vue/react etc   just check the name of the "email" field on the form.  That needs to match your new field title

Answer (score 0):

//this is in the AuthenticatedUsers trait

```
    /**
     * Get the needed authorization credentials from the request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    protected function credentials(Request $request)
    {
        return $request->only($this->username(), 'password');
    }
```

You need to make sure the post form on the login page is passing password and ACTIVE_DIRECTORY_USER. The request is grabbing $this->username which is ACTIVE_DIRECTORY_USER and the password field posted from the login form / blade file.

Flow:  A form is shown.  The form has fields email and password as inputs.  Those are "posted" to the login controller $request->email and $request->password.    Default laravel grabs only those two fields in the "credentials" method on the AuthenticadedUsers trait by using $this->username.   However you are changing $this->username , but not changing the form post.  So it's looking for $this->ACTIVE_DIRECTORY_USER un the post $request but still only has $this->email and $this->password.  Update your login.blade.php file to change the email field to ACTIVE_DIRECTORY_USER so it exists in the request.

Comment: output when i dump the credentials function with the request : ```array['ACTIVE_DIRECTORY_USER => 'test', 'password' => 'test]'```

Comment: yeah update the login form.   its passing email and password as form fields.  you need to change it from email to ACTIVE_DIRECTORY_USER in the form before it posts to the login controller. Right now, $request-> ACTIVE_DIRECTORY_USER does not exist  but $request->email does.

Comment: alternatively add this method to your login controller
  protected function credentials(Request $request)
    {
        return $request->only('email', 'password');
    }

Comment: i have already done that :( look at my post i edited it with the login form

Comment: protected function credentials(Request $request)
    { 
    dd($request->all());
        //return $request->only($this->username(), 'password');
    }

Comment: like i say above, ```array['ACTIVE_DIRECTORY_USER => 'test', 'password' => 'test]'```with also the token csrf

Comment: I have seen you type this twice:  I just want to be sure its not a typo mistake: array['ACTIVE_DIRECTORY_USER => should be array['ACTIVE_DIRECTORY_USER' =>      with single quotes around 'ACTIVE_DIRECTORY_USER'

Comment: yeah sorry i made a typo, i have ```array['ACTIVE_DIRECTORY_USER' => 'test', 'password' => 'test']```... Unfortunately that is not a typo mistake... :(

Comment: Try a forgot my password email